# Get path of JavaVM without PATH variable (Windows)

Tags: java, path, jvm, runtime, find

I want to start a java program on a windows system with installed JavaRE. Often the PATH-variable isn't set, so I have to finde the JavaRE. How could I realize this?

Comment: In what cases is `PATH` not set? It's defined by default since Windows 95.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could You be more specific about Your problem? Main JRE executables (java.exe, javaw.exe, javaws.exe) are normally found in %WINDIR%/System32 directory, which is already in %PATH%.

Comment: Wait, no their not. They exist in %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: Just check Your %WINDIR%/System32, You'll find dups there. Don't remember win specifics in details, AFAIR, they are held there to point to default JVM (in case several JVMs are installed)